# How do I convert into PDF?

Tags: pdftex, text

I've written document in LaTeX, but I don't know how to convert my .tex file into a PDF file. I'm using texMaker in the Russian language, and I couldn't find a way to typeset in this version of LaTeX.

Here is the view of my LaTeX:

[image]

How do I convert it into PDF in LaTeX?

When I run quick build, it gives me the following errors:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) First of all, this is an English language site, so most user may not understand Russia -- therefore, change the language of the software before screenshoting. Secondly, I see that you did compile your document, and there are some errors. Maybe the cause is the configuration. Can you add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and a screenshot of your `Configure TeXmaker` windows?

Comment: Have you read how to use Texmaker? The [main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZV4D.png) on the [Texmaker homepage](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) shows a button called "Quick Build" and "View PDF". Have you clicked those?

Comment: sorry for Russian interface of program Latex I change it

Comment: @Werner In the OP's [original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqnTZ.png), we can see that he did compile the document (of course by something like "Quick Build"). The fact is, it didn't output a PDF file.

Comment: @JahongirSabirov Have you installed a TeX distribution like MiKTeX or TeX Live *before* TeXmaker?

Comment: Yes I've installed MikTex

Comment: Stay away from thesis.cls -> https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: You dhould be more careful about your punctuation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're receiving is that `thesis.cls` is not available. This stems from `\documentclass{thesis}`. My assumption is that, since you're unfamiliar with (La)TeX, you just assumed that if you want to write a thesis, you should use `thesis` as your `\documentclass`. However, this is obviously incorrect since the default distributions (MiKTeX and TeX Live) do not come with a `thesis.cls` by default. Instead, start with something like `report` or `book`. Then click on *Quick Build* to compile the document, after which you can *View PDF*.

Comment: Thank you it really works. Problem was in thesis instead of writing report

Comment: Reading this answer i suddenly have a deja vu. I could swear we already have the same answer.